# Any data table query builder available, like sql query builder?

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, datatable

I am new in net I want to use data table instead of a database. 
I want to know  that why is data table query different from an sql query? 
I want to find a value from data table:

```
  SELECT dbo.General_Ledger.Entry_Amount FROM dbo.General_Ledger WHERE Account_number=lbDebit_Account_numer
```

and

```
using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(con))
        {
            int index = lbDebit_Account.FindString(txtDebit_Account.Text);
            if (0 <= index)
            {
                lbDebit_Account.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
            SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT *FROM dbo.General_Ledger", connect);

            DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
            da3.Fill(dt1);
            string lbDebit_Account_numer = lbDebit_Account.SelectedValue.ToString();
            string row;
            row= Convert.ToString(dt1.Select(string.Format("'Account_number'={0}",lbDebit_Account_numer)));
        }
```

I want to perform this  query:

```
SELECT dbo.General_Ledger.Entry_Amount FROM dbo.General_Ledger WHERE Account_number=lbDebit_Account_numer
```

Answer (score 0):

So you'll want to parameterize your query:

```
SqlDataAdapter da3 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM dbo.General_Ledger WHERE Account_number = @Account_number");
da3.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Account_number", lbDebit_Account.SelectedValue);

DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
da3.Fill(dt1);
```

and now you'll have just the one row you want and you can recover it like this:

```
DataRow dr = dt1.Rows[0];
```

and then you can grab values off of that row a number of different ways:

```
var val = dr[0]; // grabs the value of the first column in the result list
var val = dr["fieldname"] // grabs the value of a specific field name
```

and there are even some methods that will returned typed data because the aforementioned return an `object` since the underlying value could be a number of things. So, if it were a string field you were after you could do something like:

```
var val = dr.Field<string>(0) // grabs the value of the first column and returns it typed as a string
var val = dr.Field<string>("fieldname") // grabs a field and returns it typed as a string
```

Answer (score 0):

It very simple, u want to filter the DataTable[dt1] base on this string[lbDebit_Account_numer]

```
DataRow dr = dt1.Select("Account_number = '"+lbDebit_Account_numer ="'");
```

u can use

> AND OR

operators

> single code['] need for string variables to compare.

here u get data-row, all cell will in an array format you select any cell.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use DefaultView.RowFilter property of DataTable class.

Example:

```
dataTable.DefaultView.RowFilter = "Account_number=1";
```